# Android Studio Errors, why can't I make a basic menu without a bunch of problems?

Tags: android, compiler-errors

This is the tutorial I am following here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGcMLu1GJEc

The errors I'm getting seem unrelated to as to why I'm not getting a nav view, but for some reason it break my preview on the right as you can see, but also when I build project I get this ugly default Hello World activity.

What am I doing wrong here? I even copy and pasted the code the tutorial the guy made available just to make sure I didn't make any mistakes. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a screenshot of my errors:

[image]

Comment: I'd agree, those errors seem unrelated.  Not sure offhand what the real problem is, but hopefully that helps you narrow it down...

Comment: Errors shown are related to the emulator, normally shouldn't be affecting your app, try to Clean project from Build option might help with previews in some cases. As for why activity is wrong you should paste your code related to the landing activity so we can have a look at it